# Set up REST routes in Express JS for Ajax only to use with Backbone

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, routes, express

I am working on re-writing an existing web site using Node.js with Express.

Front-end of the site will use Backbone JS and thus I need to have all necessary routes comply with native Backbone sync. Now most of URL's the client and for Backbone sync will be same. But they won't work for regular GET as they would need to return JSON.

So I am thinking, would it be a good idea to add extension to Model/Collection URLs in Backbone, such as `.json`, and in Express to have this for every route:

```
app.get('/p/:topCategory/:category/:product.:format', function(req, res) { ... });
```

Where `if (req.params.id == 'json')` than we send JSON, otherwise we render HTML?

Or is there a better approach? Please help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The better way of doing this would be to use the content negotiation feature in Express 3.x, namely `res.format`:

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L299-378

```
res.format({
  text: function(){
    res.send('hey');
  },

  html: function(){
    res.send('<p>hey</p>');
  },

  json: function(){
    res.send({ message: 'hey' });
  }
});
```

You approach is also ok, Yammer for ex. is using the same approach: http://developer.yammer.com/api/#message-viewing

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did not find res.format() in Express docs though. But I found req.is('html') or req.is('json'). I guess either one should work but res.format() looks better as it's function and I don't need to use if/else if for res.is().

Comment: It isn't in the documentation yet because Express 3.x is new and the site needs to be updated (that will happen very soon as far as I know).

Answer (score 6):

Use `Accept` headers in your requests: `Accept: application/json` if you want to receive JSON, `Accept: text/HTML` if you want HTML.

Comment: And how do I set this up on the Node side?

Comment: You use standard JavaScript text-parsing techniques (regular expressions, etc.) to look through `req.headers` for anything starting with `Accept:`. The way I'd do it would be to send out a JSON response if any of them are asking for JSON, and an HTML response if none of them are.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative that also checks that the "X-Requested-With" header is set for jQuery et al.

```
var onlyAllowJsonRequests = function (req, res, next) {

    var acceptJson = (req.accepted.length && _.any(req.accepted, function (acc) { return acc.value.indexOf("json") !== -1 }));

    // also check that "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest" header is set
    if (acceptJson && (req.xhr === true)) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.send(406, "Not Acceptable");
    }
};

app.use(onlyAllowJsonRequests);
```

NB underscore is a depency.

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct way to do this is to implement **content negotiation** into your application. Yeah, Express 3.x facility is a way to do it and provides a direct answer to your question, but I don't think it's the best way to do it because it places the content negotiation responsibility in the routing logic. I don't think that's a good place for it because it doesn't follow the [single responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) principle, having put the **content negotiation** in routing logic.

I've taken a stab at implementing **content negotiation** in my [blog engine](https://github.com/ijoey/joeyguerra/blob/master/represent.js); reviewing that might help guide you in a good direction. The gist is that the code determines the file extension via **content negotiation** logic. Then, with the file extension, it wants to find the corresponding view file, renders it into a response and sends it back to the client. The idea is that it responds with the requested resource in the requested representation per the content negotiation. The [routing logic](https://github.com/ijoey/joeyguerra/blob/master/resources/index.js#L23) only specifies a view, but has no idea about content negotiation. That happens outside of the routing logic which makes for a more flexible design.

The result of this design is the ability to ask for a specific representation of the resource like:

http://blog.joeyguerra.com/index.json and get a JSON representation
http://blog.joeyguerra.com/index.phtml and get partial (or an HTML fragment) HTML representation
http://blog.joeyguerra.com/index.xml and get an XML representation.